# BigQuery: insert rows, but it's not written

Tags: insert, google-bigquery

I am updating a list of rows using the method `tabledata().insertAll` from the bigquery object. After the execution, the return shows no errors. However, my tables still continue with no data written.

Could be a problem of permission. If so, why there's no errors returned?

Thanks

Comment: It may take few minutes until your data shows in the query after you send first streaming requests. Have you tried to wait few minutes before you check?

Comment: You maybe don't read correctly the errors, I've seen many users making that mistake.

Comment: If you provide me your project id and table, I can take a look from our (BigQuery's) end.

Comment: There are two ways errors are returned: either a failure of the api call, or you may get receive per-row errors within a successful api request. See `insertErrors` at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/insertAll#response. Can you clarify which of these you mean by "no errors returned"?

Answer (score 9):

This can happen if you do the insert right after deleting and re-creating the table.
The streaming buffer of a deleted table is not deleted right at the time that table is deleted, which can cause new inserts to be delivered to this old streaming buffer.

From [BigQuery documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors#metadata-errors-for-streaming-inserts):

> deleting and/or recreating a table may create a period of time where streaming inserts are effectively delivered to the old table and will not be present in the newly created table.

And in this case, no errors would be returned.

---

References:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors#metadata-errors-for-streaming-inserts
- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php/issues/871#issuecomment-361339800
- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery

Comment: is there a resolution to this? does the stream eventually end and move to the correct table?

Comment: as far as I remember, yes. Eventually the old streaming buffer is deleted and then new inserts made from this point will be delivered to the correct table.  
Edit: the github issue that I linked above also mentioned some approaches to deal with this issue, e.g. https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/issues/871#issuecomment-434708110